# salesforce Dataloader : field 'Description' can not be filtered in a query call

Tags: data-loader, tasks, emailmessage, data-extract, dataloader.io

I am using dataloader to look for and extract certain emails(tasks) that must have the word "igloo" in them, I tried to do 'description' contains "igloo" and got an error saying the description field cannot be used to filter (so why even include it?)

apparently because 'Description' is a longtextarea-type it cannot be used in a query?
[image]
any work-arounds to this or to my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Long Text Area fields can't be a filter, but you can return it:

```
SELECT Description FROM Task
```

However, you can find records that match that word, just use SOSL instead:

```
FIND {igloo} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Task(Description)
```

Note that this searches all fields on the object, not just Description, so you'll need to check which records match in a separate post-processing step.

Long Text Area fields (and a few other types) can't be filtered, because the database cannot handle that kind of filter efficiently.